# C++: Binary Tree Remove Root Node

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary-search-tree

I have a program that allows a user to add and delete (amongst other things) an account to a binary search tree. I have tested/debugged this code and have found the area causing the issue, I'm just not quite sure how to fix it. I can add accounts fine, and I can remove all but the root node without error. Here is my function:

```
    if((current->llink==NULL && current->rlink != NULL) || (current->llink != NULL && current->rlink==NULL)){
        if(current->llink==NULL && current->rlink != NULL){
            if(trailcurrent->llink==current){
                trailcurrent->llink=current->rlink;
                delete current;
                current=NULL;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
            else{
                trailcurrent->rlink=current->rlink;
                delete current;
                current=NULL;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(trailcurrent->llink==current){
                trailcurrent->llink=current->llink;
                delete current;
                current=NULL;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
            else{
                trailcurrent->rlink=current->llink;
                delete current;
                current=NULL;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if(current->llink==NULL && current->rlink==NULL){
        if(trailcurrent->llink==current) // This 'if' statement crashes the program with a read violation when deleting the root.
            trailcurrent->llink=NULL;
        else
            trailcurrent->rlink=NULL;
        delete current;
        cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
        return;
    }
    if(current->llink != NULL && current->rlink != NULL){
        nodeType<accountType>* check=current->rlink;
        if((current->llink==NULL)&&(current->rlink==NULL)){
            current=check;
            delete check;
            current->rlink=NULL;
            cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
        }
        else{
            if((current->rlink)->llink!=NULL){
                nodeType<accountType>* leftCurrent;
                nodeType<accountType>* leftTrailCurrent;
                leftTrailCurrent=current->rlink;
                leftCurrent=(current->rlink)->llink;
                while(leftCurrent->llink != NULL){
                    leftTrailCurrent=leftCurrent;
                    leftCurrent=leftCurrent->llink;
                }
                current->info=leftCurrent->info;
                delete leftCurrent;
                leftTrailCurrent->llink=NULL;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
            else{
                nodeType<accountType>* temp=current->rlink;
                current->info=temp->info;
                current->rlink=temp->rlink;
                delete temp;
                cout << "Account #:" << acctNum << " has been removed from the list." << endl;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

With the line that is causing me issues, do I have to have an 'if' statement before it, where trailcurrent == NULL;? If so, inside of that 'if' statement would I do something similar to

```
if(current->rlink>current->llink){}
```

Comment: I'm going to step up right now and tell you (a) we have no idea what your data types look like; remember we can't see your whole project, only you can, and (b) I can *guarantee* you a "greater-than" comparison of two link pointers, as in `current->rlink>current->llink`, is not only likely *not* what you want to do, but unless *both* pointers are logically from the same physical *singular* allocation (including 1-past-end), it isn't even standard-defined behavior.

Comment: I am fully aware that you cannot see my code, and that you don't know the data types. and for the comparison, I meant something along the lines of finding a way to shift them up the tree. (so in reality it would be the data in the node in the link) I can't think of how to do it off the top of my head. Do you really NEED to know my data type? (Can't you just assume it has a variable of your choice to explain what I need to do?)

Comment: When the root node is deleted, it is replaced by the right or left subtree (if they exist).  Review you data structures texts.